# CVS checkout: invalid character in directory name

Tags: version-control, cvs, invalid-characters

I'm trying to clone an old CVS repository with:

```
cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@ivan.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/ivan co -P ivan
```

However, one of the directories in the repository contains a seemingly invalid character in its name, shown as `�` in [ViewVC](http://ivan.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ivan/ivan/Doc/) and as `?` in the error message `cvs co` gives me:

```
cvs [checkout aborted]: cannot make directory CVS in ivan/Doc/Ty?t: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this? I'm okay with excluding the directory from the checkout if renaming it isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by running the `co` command *twice*.

On the first run, CVS stops the checkout when it encounters the directory with the invalid name. On the second run, it adds all the remaining files it didn't import on the first run (except the invalid directory).

It also complains `cvs checkout: cannot remove ivan/Doc/Ty?t: No such file or directory` after the second `co`. The directory is there, named `Ty%F6t`, but it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `.cvsignore`. You can find details [here](http://evscm.org/manual/html/cvsignore.html). Assuming [this](http://ivan.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ivan/ivan/) is what you're trying to check out, try creating a `.cvsignore` file with the following it.

```
Doc
```

Comment: I tried adding `.cvsignore` to the directory where I run `co` and also tried putting it in an `ivan` directory and running `co` from its parent directory, but nothing changed. However, I managed to checkout all other directories by running `co` twice, see my answer.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!